# Content of Computed property not picked up by the template, but is logged ok in lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, computed-properties

I am creating a webshop where you have the choice to order products apart from the cart without interfering with the contents of the cart. The way I am realizing this is by sharing a page for both your cart items and a single product. It checks if the productID param has been set and in that case it uses different data.

This is the function I have written:

```js
    computed : {
        products: function() {
            if ( this.$route.query.pid ) {
                var product = [{}]
                axios.get(`/api/products/${this.pid}`).then(response => {
                    product[0].id = response.data[0].id
                    product[0].name = response.data[0].name
                    product[0].units = response.data[0].units
                    product[0].image = response.data[0].product_image[0].image
                    product[0].price = response.data[0].price
                    product[0].quantity = 1
                })
                return Object.assign(product)
            } else {
                return this.$store.state.cart
            }
        }
    },
```

Here is the lifecycle hook (beforeMount) which successfully retrieves the data:

```js
    beforeMount() {
        console.log(this.products)
    }
```

Now the problem is that the products property is seen as empty by the template. It's completely fine when I go to this page without the query param, it just can't find the computed data for a single product.

How do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the point of `return Object.assign(product)` ?

Comment: I figured I could use that since I am using a for loop, so I don't need two add extra code for the single product.

Answer (score 2):

[vue/no-async-in-computed-properties](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-async-in-computed-properties.html)

> Computed properties and functions should be synchronous. Asynchronous actions inside them may not work as expected and can lead to an unexpected behaviour, that's why you should avoid them. If you need async computed properties you might want to consider using additional plugin [vue-async-computed]

*Property not getting picked up by the template, but the lifecycle hook is able to get the data using a computed property*

Only reason you see something in the console is that most modern browsers [log objects as live data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects) (as soon as the object updates, console updates too). So what you see in the console is not the value of the object at the time `console.log` was executed but it's value later in the time. You can confirm this by doing `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.products)))` instead...

To solve the problem, use `watch` instead of `computed`

```js
data() {
  return {
    products: []
  }
},
watch: {
  '$route.query.pid': {
    handler: function(newValue) {
      if(newValue) {
        axios.get(`/api/products/${newValue}`).then(response => {
          var product = {
            id: response.data[0].id,
            name: response.data[0].name,
            units: response.data[0].units
            image: response.data[0].product_image[0].image
            price: response.data[0].price
            quantity: 1
          }
          this.products = []
          this.products.push(product)
      } else this.products = this.$store.state.cart
    },
    immediate: true
  }
},
```